# What is the data type to use for a description?

Tags: mysql, sqlite, types, sqldatatypes

I would like to know what data type I need to use for a description.

example:

```
Baseball cap by adidas Originals 
-   Made from cotton
-   Embroidered brand logo to the front
-   Five panel styling
-   Ventilation holes to the side
```

What data type do I need to use so when I want to use this data it still contain the spaces and indents?

Comment: use `VARCHAR` spaces and indentions are still string literals.

Comment: @JW. Thank you for your answer. Do you know how I can still keep the indents and spaces if I want to render this data in the UITextView in xcode?

Comment: Have you tries doing this. Storing this data in data base an then republishing in application, does it make any diffrence.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with the data type.  You can use `varchar` or `text`.  If you are trying to render as HTML then you'll want to render it between `<pre>` tags.

Comment: Do you know how I can still keep the indents and spaces if I want to render this data in the UITextView in xcode?

Comment: Not sure on that one.  You should probably go ahead and accept an answer and post a new question with your exact problem.  Show your code, what you are expecting to see, and what you are actually seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Your text will be saved as it is, your text render is the one that has to understand the line breaks, indents, etc.

You can use any alphanumeric datatype.

Comment: Do you know how I can still keep the indents and spaces if I want to render this data in the UITextView in xcode?